# URL to Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, url

I don't know how to make this working. I want to make arrays from URL:

```
index.php?address=someaddress&telephone=12345&customer=Customer Name&p_name[0]=ProductOne&p_name[1]=ProductTwo&p_price[0]=1&p_price[1]=10&p_name[2]...
```

There is an api, which is working like this:

```
$api‐>addItem(array(
        'name' => 'ProductOne',
        'price' => '123',
    ));

$api­‐>addItem(array(
        'name' => 'ProductTwo',
        'price' => '32',
    ));
```

Is there any way to make arrays like this (=api request `$api->addItem(array`) from the URL? `$api­‐>addItem(array` can be used multiple times.

Comment: Are there really `$` in the URL?  Are those supposed to be `&`?

Comment: Is this URL a string, or are you going to this URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have control over the URL?  If so, I'd change how you send your values.

Instead of:

```
name1=ProductOne&price1=123&name2=ProductTwo&price2=32
```

I'd use:

```
name[]=ProductOne&price[]=123&name[]=ProductTwo&price[]=32
```

The `[]` turn them into arrays, meaning `$_GET['name']` is now an array.  then you can `foreach` over it.

```
foreach($_GET['name'] as $k=>$v){
    $api->addItem(array(
        'name' => $v,
        'price' => $_GET['price'][$k]
    ));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have full control over the URL. I think your code is what I exactly need, I am going to try it.

Comment: hmm, I can't make it working http://bit.ly/KuQ4H8. So the only way is parse_str&parse_url? The problem with that, there will be additional elements in the URL, which will be not in this array. I update the question.

Comment: @Adrian: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: The array in the URL must be p_name[0], p_name[1]...  I can't make array like this p_name[]. index.php?address=someaddress&telephone=12345&customer=Customer Name&p_name[0]=ProductOne&p_name[1]=ProductTwo&p_quantity[0]=1&p_quantity[1]=1

Comment: @Adrian: ...What's the problem?  You *can* put values inside the `[]`, but you don't have to.  It'll work either way.

Comment: The problem is, I only get one product from output of your code. Here is a test page&url: http://bit.ly/Jk1TlX

Comment: @Adrian: Can you add `var_dump($_GET);` to that page?

Comment: @Adrian: As you can see: `$_GET['p_name']` is an array as is `$_GET['p_quantity']`.  Double check the code you're using.  Try this:  `foreach($_GET['p_name'] as $k=>$v){var_dump($v,$_GET['p_quantity'][$k]);}`  It should print all the values.

Comment: Yes, but they are actually one pair, or it should be not? Here is the code, which generate the URL: http://d.pr/n/tNXy

Comment: @Adrian: That code looks fine.  And your test page (http://bit.ly/Jk1TlX) echos both values, so what's the problem?

Comment: I modified my test page to your new code (var_dump). Looks good, but where the $api->addItem part is going? Here is the source code: http://mihalko.eu/sf/index.phps

Comment: It's worked, but I can't combine it with the var_dump part: foreach($_GET['p_name'] as $k=>$v){
$q = array(
        'name' => $v,
        'quantity' => var_dump($v,$_GET['p_quantity'][$k])
);

} /please check phps source, if it's unreadable/ This is not working. (the $q= would be the api->addItem, that's ok -just for test I added this variable to print output )

Comment: @Adrian: Yeah `var_dump` is just for testing.

Comment: The real problem is, I can't get all values and add them to arrays. I understand, that the var_dump give me all values, but how to add them to multiple arrays? Without vardump I only get one array.

Comment: @Adrian: That's because you were resetting `$q` each time you looped.  `$q=array(); foreach($_GET['p_name'] as $k=>$v){$q[] = array(...)} print_r($q);`.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes, you have right. Sorry for the long chat. It's working fine now. :)

Comment: @Adrian: It's fine.  Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Thanks dqhendricks and Rocket for pointing out that you can use `parse_str()` to do the same thing.

```
$q = parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

Or you could use this (the long way):

```
function parse_query($var) {
   $var = parse_url($var, PHP_URL_QUERY);
   $var = html_entity_decode($var);
   $var = explode('&', $var);
   $arr = array();

   foreach($var as $val) {
     $x = explode('=', $val);
     $arr[$x[0]] = $x[1];
   }
   unset($val, $x, $var);
   return $arr;
}
```

Use like this:

```
$url = "http://someurl.com/click?z=26&a=761";
print_r(parse_query($url));
```

Comment: i cannot believe this got this many votes. there is already native php code to do this for you... parse_str()

Comment: `$q = parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));`

Answer (score 1):

```
// extract the query from the url string
$url = parse_url('sample.php?name1=ProductOne&price1=123&name2=ProductTwo&price2=32', PHP_URL_QUERY);
// process into array so that first element is a key, and second element is a value
parse_str($url, $output_array);
// now $output_array contains the query's variables.
```

The bigger question is why would you want to do this when these variables are already contained in `$_GET`?

Answer (score 0):

```
sample.php?name[]=Product1&name[]=Product2
```

Then in your PHP, you can see:

```
print_r($_GET['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but if what you're looking for is converting a querystring to an array you can user the `pares_str` function. in order to get only the querystring from a url you can use the `parse_url` function

```
$url = "sample.php?some_var=someval&s=4&bla=bla";
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$qs = $url_parts["query"];
$params = array();
parse_str($qs,$params);
var_dump($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like dqhendricks suggested, would it not pay to just use the raw gets and then append them to an array. I am assuming that you will always know what will be in the URL

$array_of_gets = array("address" => $_GET['address'],"telephone" => $_GET['telephone']);

and so on...